# Odd "TFPSI" cookie on various sites that doesn't go away or listen to categorizations?

Tags: html, security, cookies, session-cookies

When originally tasked with checking out some cookies that seemed active regardless of the cookie policies in place, I found a cookie labelled "tfpsi" that became quite the eyebrow raiser. Mainly due to the fact that it seemed to ignore our cookie blocker entirely & it seems to be internal. That being said, it is also found on a variety of other sites from the searches I've done. Many of which also replicate the same mannerisms as the one I found on our site.

It seems to get data based on the areas you traverse on the site, and from what I've found on descriptions it seems tied to advertising on that site.
This is all fine and dandy except for the fact this is impacting two of our sites which don't seem to have any advertising piece involved that handles this cookie and the advertising we do have is on other sites that, in theory, should have this cookie appear as well.

I also noticed that manual removal of this cookie doesn't work. It's labelled on the site as "Functional" but upon toggling functional cookies off and deleting it, it still appears on refresh?

To provide an example, the valentino website was one found to replicate the behavior:
[Here's a link](https://www.valentino.com/en-us/help/customercare/legalarea/cookiepolicy)

What I've tried:

- Manual deletion of the cookie, to which it reappears
- Categorization in cookie providers policy, to which it ignores
- Tracking the data it captures, to see where it relates to, to which I've gathered it's analytics/user tracking (likely for advertising)
- Checking if we have any companies relating to advertisements that use this cookie that can be found on our other sites, to which we have not found any.
- Checking the cookies value in console, to which I receive a code/value with no meaning based upon searches or prior knowledge.
- Searching cookie databases, to which there is little to no information and only references to other sites who also have this cookie on their site.

At this point, considering plenty of other sites having this issue I am guessing this is an intentional affect of some manner & no actual data is being sent over so it's dormant or not a major issue but it's nagging me that I have absolutely zero clue what this cookie is, where it's from or why it's there (and most importantly, only there and not on other sites).

Comment: Based on a quick search, tfpsi is likely a tracking cookie for [Teads](https://www.teads.com/?mtm_campaign=Privacy-Policy&mtm_source=Privacy-Policy-Header&mtm_medium=Privacy-Policy-ExtButton).